# patch can not apply to due to small changes in the file

Tags: couchdb, patch

I'm trying to save/restore my CouchDB configuration via a diff/patch on the `couchdb/local.ini` file:

```
 [couchdb]
 ;max_document_size = 4294967296 ; bytes
 uuid = eb3e8ea0e717f24a61fb2be26daa1f55
+file_compression = snappy

 [httpd]
 ;port = 5984
```

Alas, patch fails to apply it since the `uuid` is changing at each re-install. What would be the best way to solve this?

Or if you have a better way to handle CouchDB configuration backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use my solution only if no one have a good answer, it's not the elegantest way!**

You can write your own script, which you can run if you wish to have the backup version back to the config.

Comment: I can give you a tipp for that: Make it with python or bash.